# Does horse-armour degrade in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does horse-armour degrade? Does horse armour lose durability like with the player wearable armour? Is it repairable or enchantable?

Comment: This question is about an upcoming feature that is subject to change.

Comment: @OrcJMR That is the entire history of Minecraft. When the game changes the answers get updated or questions that are no longer valid are removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Horse armor doesn't have durability, it'll only be removed from the horse if you equip different armor on the horse. As such it is not repairable. I do not know if it can be enchanted however.

[Source: Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse_Armor)

Comment: It says that it cannot be enchanted unless in creative mode.