# Can I craft saddles and horse armour?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Are saddles and horse armour only found in dungeons, or can I craft them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot craft saddles or Horse Armour, but saddles can be found in other places than dungeons, for example through trading or fishing.

From the wiki page for [Saddles](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Saddle):

> Saddles are a rare item in the game, being found only in chests inside dungeons, abandoned mineshafts, Nether Fortresses, Desert and Jungle Temples, in blacksmith chests found in NPC villages, or by trading with a villager. Also, saddles can be "caught" with a fishing rod. Prior to horses being added, Dinnerbone stated he will not be including a crafting recipe for saddles.

And [Horse Armour](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse_armor):

> Horse armor [...] can be found in dungeons as well as Nether fortress chests, Village Blacksmith chests, Jungle Temple and Desert Temple chests, and in abandoned mineshaft minecart chests. Horse armor protects the horse from attacks. Horse armor cannot be crafted.

Comment: Another question: Can horse armor be repaired in an anvil, using another piece of whatever material the horse armor is made of? (I just looked at the related question, they don't even take damage, so ignore this) [Does Horse Armor Degrade?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117136/does-horse-armour-degrade-in-minecraft?rq=1)

Comment: Fishing is my new favourite way to get saddles.

Comment: Crafting horse armor depends on what version you are playing on.  In 13w16a, horse armor was craftable.

Source: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANBR0gNkDBk

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not craft horse armor or saddle. You can find they in dungeon chests.
One more information: the saddle is a very rare item, but you can find horsearmor in many places. For example in a desert temple.

[image: Minecraft desert temple]